# Python создание csv

Tags: python, csv

Задача такая:

```
Создать файл, с верхом:
    CATEGORY_ID - (ключевое поле) порядковый номер категории (начиная с «1»).
    PARENT_CATEGORY_ID
    CATEGORY_NAME
    CATEGORY_URL
Занести туда список из 3 элементов (можно брать не список, а другой любой элемент)
Получить CATEGORY_ID добавленной строки
```

Создал метод, куда передается список

```
def add_cagetory_in_csv(category):
    with open(filename_category, "w", newline="") as file:
        columns = ["CATEGORY_ID", "PARENT_CATEGORY_ID", "CATEGORY_NAME", "CATEGORY_URL"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(category)
```

Как сделать в файле автоматическую генерацию поля CATEGORY_ID?

Comment: А что в `category` лежит?

Comment: @предварительно список, но можно на другое что-нибудь поменять

Comment: Мне не понятно что у вас за проблема :) Вызывайте `index = 0` `add_cagetory_in_csv(index, 0, "name", "url")` `index += 1` нужное количество раз. Если готовые данные есть, то проблем тем более нет -- в цикле перебрать и увеличивая индекс добавлять. Если нужно добавлять в текущий csv новые данные, то считываете его и берете последную строку и от ее `id` инициализируете `index`

Comment: я думал, что можно сделать это как-то автоматически, без заведения переменной-счетчика

Comment: Будь, это база данных, то можно было -- sqlite например да, а так -- ручками :) Да и, почему бы, вам изначально в базу добавлять? При желании могли бы из нее экспортировать как csv